# How to set and show an image on tizen native widget?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I was trying to set image on tizen native widget but I dont know how to retrieve path and apply it.
Below is my try:

```
//image
                char full_path[PATH_MAX] = { 0, };
                data_get_resource_path("images/testimg.png", full_path, (int) PATH_MAX); //getting error here.



                    Evas_Object *image;
                    image = elm_image_add(wid->conform);

                    elm_object_item_data_set(image, full_path); //how to set path?

                    elm_image_no_scale_set(image, EINA_TRUE);
                    elm_image_resizable_set(image, EINA_TRUE, EINA_TRUE);
                    /* Tell the image to keep original aspect ratio */
                    elm_image_aspect_fixed_set(image, EINA_TRUE);
                    /* Then let the image fill the entire object */
                    elm_image_fill_outside_set(image, EINA_TRUE);

                    evas_object_show(image);
```

Tried from doc of image from tizen dev website, no information exclusively for path setting.

How can I add a simple image and show it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative file paths and set image files to efl object.

There are many sample applications. For example, `BuddyUI Sample Application` show how to get image file path

A image file is in `res/images/wc_contact_bg.png`.

```c
#define IMAGE_CONTACT_BG "images/wc_contact_bg.png"

static bool app_create(void *user_data)
{
    Evas_Object *win = NULL;
    Eina_List *item_list = NULL;
    Evas_Object *main_view_layout = NULL;
    Evas_Object *naviframe = NULL;
    int item_count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char default_img_path[PATH_MAX] = { 0, };
    char edj_path[PATH_MAX] = { 0, };

    data_get_resource_path(EDJ_FILE, edj_path, sizeof(edj_path));
    data_get_resource_path(IMAGE_CONTACT_BG, default_img_path, sizeof(default_img_path));
```

You can get the absolute path to the application resource directory by `app_get_resource_path`.

```c
void data_get_resource_path(const char *file_in, char *file_path_out, int file_path_max)
{
    char *res_path = app_get_resource_path();
    if (res_path) {
        snprintf(file_path_out, file_path_max, "%s%s", res_path, file_in);
        free(res_path);
    }
}
```

You can find a lot of information at the link below.
[File System Directory Hierarchy](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/training/native-application/understanding-tizen-programming/file-system-directory-hierarchy?langredirect=1)